# ERROR: Please disable the open_basedir setting to continue in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, server, laravel-5

I have got an error in Laravel 5.2:

> "ERROR: Please disable the open_basedir setting to continue."

Is this coding problem or server problem? How can i solve this problem without disable `open_basedir` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to either disable it within either: `httpd.conf` or `php.ini` (server-side) or request that your host provider can perform this action for you.

To my understanding, this must be disabled to continue with using Laravel.

Unfortunately (again, as far as I am aware), there is no 'workaround'.

Comment: I don't have httpd.conf or php.ini file. How can i disable it?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud, Do you have root access to the server? If not, I would suggest speaking to your host provider and request they disable it. Unfortunately there is no .htaccess 'workaround' for this

Comment: Yes i have root access permission

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud, If you have root access and SSH then you will be able to disable `open_basedir` via the command line.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud, that is file manager access... Not root access. Do you run a server yourself or have a host provider?

Comment: for command line access which software is better? I have host provider.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud, I would suggest speaking to your host provider as you won't have the access needed to make the relevant changes